# using FiddlerCore as view-only

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, fiddler

I'm using **fiddlerCore** in order to capture the network activity.

I downloaded the "fiddlercore demo 1" from the fiddler wiki page (http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore-demo) and I removed the *Fiddler.CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = false;* line.

When I execute this CosnoleWindow application and I'm connecting to https sites I get *"The site's security certificate is not trusted!"*. In the application I get the following error:

> **LogString: fiddler.network.streaming> Streaming of response #72 to client failed: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.".

It happens only when the application is running.

I want only to **view** the network data and not to affect it.
How can I use the fiddlerCore for this purpose ?

Thanks,
Tal Yaari

Comment: Rather than remove the configuration, have you tried changing the value to `true`? (It could be the configuration mirrors a hardcoded default of `false`.)

Comment: IgnoreServerCertErrors concerns whether FiddlerCore ignores problems with the *server's* certificate. It has nothing to do with FiddlerCore's cert.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use Fiddler to connect to to sites using HTTPS you will actually need to perform a "man-in-the-middle" attack on yourself. In other words you need to set up Fiddler to appear to be a server with a valid certificate. This is documented here http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore-faq

Comment: And if you *don't* want to see the encrypted traffic, remove DecryptSSL from the FiddlerCoreStartupFlags passed into the Startup method.

Comment: Thanks. I want to see the encrypted traffic. 
Is there any way of creating this DO_NOT_TRUST_FIDDLERROOT dragging by code ?